# Are downvotes at reputation 1 applied later?

Tags: support, reputation, downvotes

I see a lot of users seemingly just registered (reputation 1) asking bad questions and consequently receiving downvotes.

Apart from the signal effect to tell the user (who likely doesn't know what's going on) I wonder what happens to the reputation. So if the user later recieves some upvote, will the downvote be applied then?

```
1. Rep 1 -> Downvote -1 -> Rep 1 -> Upvote +10 -> Rep 11
2. Rep 1 -> Upvote +10 -> Rep 11 -> Downvote -1 -> Rep 10
3. Rep 1 -> Downvote -1 -> Rep 1 -> Upvote +10 -> Rep 10
```

If case 1 is true, does it mean, that, if the downvote later is retracted, will he get back the 1 point (which was not subtracted due to the cap) and thus get an additional Rep for it?

Comment: No, the down vote will not be applied later. If you're at 1 and receive an upvote you go to 11 no matter how many downvotes you got while at 1 rep.

Comment: Your calculations are a bit odd. The "-1" is applied to the downvoter, not the downvotee who gets a "-2" on their reputation. The score of the post affects the downvotee no matter when it's made in the sense that the score of all of their posts determines if they can ask/answer.

Comment: @Scratte, yes, you are right, but the actual nubers don't matter that much, because the principle is the same. Anyway, the quesiton is already answered with the duplicate, I didn't find when I tried to search for it.

Comment: No in fact low reputation user get the following notification on vote "_Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 125 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score._". Once you reach the reputation  you can come back an vote that time it will have an effect other than showing a notification . But it force low rep user to maintain a list of reviewed post and to review it slowly in order to not trigger the voting fraud.